# Using not operation in hamcrest

Tags: hamcrest

I was recently trying to assert the inequality in one of the test. However I wasnt able to find the appropriate matcher in hamcrest. 
What I ideally want to do is something like.

```
assertThat(2 , isNot(3));
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
assertThat(2 , is(not(3)));
```

Comment: And unless `is()` is the only matcher present, it's unnecessary syntactic sugar. `assertThat(2 , not(3));` also works here.

Answer (score 19):

Be sure you import it:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.not;
```